# Iniciar função pelo Onclick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Boa Tarde Amigos.

Minha questão é o seguinte, possuo um script que fica lendo um .log basicamente em tempo real e o mostra em tela, mas a questão é que ele inicia com o DOM, gostaria que ele iniciasse apenas a partir do click no botão, poderiam me ajudar ??

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
        $sessionID = 'log'.$_GET['s'];
        session_id($sessionID);
        session_start();
        $handle = fopen('/\\cordas\instance-8480\log\server.log', 'r');
        if (isset($_SESSION['offset'])) {
            $data = stream_get_contents($handle, -1, $_SESSION['offset']);
            echo nl2br($data);
        } else {
            fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);
    } 
      $_SESSION['offset'] = ftell($handle);
      exit();
    }

    $randomSession = rand();
```

?>

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function( ) {
            $.repeat(1000, function() {
                $.get('automacao_tela.php?ajax&s=<?=$randomSession;?>', function(data) {
                    $('#tail').append(data);
                });
            });
        });
  </script>

<form action="?automacao=ok" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="log-btn" >INICIAR PROCESSO</button>
</form>

 <div id="tail" class="widget-stats-list-log">
    Starting up...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque isso

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function( ) {
        $.repeat(1000, function() {
            $.get('automacao_tela.php?ajax&s=<?=$randomSession;?>', function(data) {
                $('#tail').append(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

para isso

```
$(document).ready(function( ) {
$('.log-btn').click(function()) {
        $.repeat(1000, function() {
            $.get('automacao_tela.php?ajax&s=<?=$randomSession;?>', function(data) {
                $('#tail').append(data);
            });
        });
    });                    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, mas ainda não funcionou dessa forma a qual me passou.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelo retorno @Leonardo. fiz da seguinte forma, mas mesmo assim não funciona:

```
$('.log-btn').click(function()) {
            $.repeat(1000, function() {
                $.get('automacao_tela.php?ajax&s=<?=$randomSession;?>', function(data) {
                    $('#tail').append(data);
                });
            });
        });
```